# convert from string to array and display in php

Tags: php

I have this string

```
$search_data = '{"Search Engine":"High Schools","Population":300,"Avg GPA":"3.2","Graduation Rate":"98%"}';
$data = explode(",", $search_data);
$display_data = "<br/>";
foreach($data as $item){
    $display_data .= "<span>$item</span><br/>";
}
echo $display_data;
```

What is echoed looks like this:

```
{"Search Engine":"High Schools"
"Population":300
"Avg GPA:"3.2"
"Graduation Rate":"98%"}
```

How can i properly format this so the displayed text looks like this:

```
Search Engine: High Schools
Population : 300
Avg GPA: 3.2
Graduation Rate: 98%
```

Any helpful tips will be appreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the data is JSON you can just decode it to an assocative array. Then foreach over to print each key and value.

```
$search_data = '{"Search Engine":"High Schools","Population":300,"Avg GPA":"3.2","Graduation Rate":"98%"}';

foreach (json_decode($search_data, true) as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

#### Output

```
Search Engine: High Schools
Population: 300
Avg GPA: 3.2
Graduation Rate: 98%
```